# Number of numbers need to check before finding a prime

Tags: prime-numbers

I am interested in (roughly estimating) how many random integers do I have to check before I find a prime of size say $100$ digits.

I was thinking like so:

Let the number of primes up to $X$ be denoted by $\pi(X)$. The famous Prime Number Theorem says that
$$
\lim_{X\to\infty}\frac{\pi(X)}{X/\ln(X)}=1
$$ 
so a randomly chosen number $N$ has probability
$$
P(N \ being \ prime)=\frac{1}{\ln(N)}
$$
of being prime.

Now I need numbers of size $10^{100}$ which means I have
$$
\frac{1}{\ln(10^{100})}=\frac{1}{100}\cdot \frac{1}{\ln(10)}\approx 0,02305
$$

so the chance of picking a prime is roughly $2,3\%$ therefore I need (in theory) to check at least $50$ numbers before I hit a prime.

Is my reasoning correct?

Thank you!

Edit:

I made a silly calculator mistake the correct value is:
$$
\frac{1}{230}\approx 0,00434
$$
so I need to check a  bit over $200$ numbers say $250$.

Comment: You are not going to bother checking even numbers, are you?

Comment: The numerical value is not correct. It is about $\frac{1}{230}$. Of course, with trial division (lets say upto $100$) , you can speed up the search and you increase the chance to find a prime by a factor of $8.3$ if you try large numbers.. Basically , your approach is correct however.

Comment: No definitely not, in a realistic case (further non ending with 5 etc) :) 
But the question said "random integers" so I assume they mean actually a randomly picked integer

Comment: @Peter thank you. I corrected the question. I made a silly calculator mistake

Comment: I have recently read that this approach (probability $\frac{1}{\ln(N)}$) has been refuted, but this should not be critical. I do not think that the error is big.

Comment: Your calculation is correct. However, as is pointed out above, picking and testing random numbers is a very inefficient way of finding primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a Polymath Project (see [link here](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Finding_primes)) to come up with an efficient deterministic algorithm to find a prime larger than a given number $N$ (equivalent to a prime of size at least $\lceil \log_2 N \rceil$ bits in your notation). Terence Tao led this effort and a paper (see abstract [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3956)) was published at the end of the project.

See also Terence Tao's blog [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/a-deterministic-way-to-find-primes/) for a discussion of the results of the project.

I quote from the introduction of the paper, which confirms your guess of the randomized complexity, as being essentially $O(\log^{O(1)}N)$:

> Note that if one allows probabilistic algorithms [..] one can accomplish this in time
>   polynomial in the length of $N$ (i.e. in time at most $\log^{O(1)} N$); indeed, one can select
>   integers in [N, 2N] at random and test each one for primality. [..] Using algorithms such as the AKS algorithm,
>   each such integer can be tested in time at most $\log^{O(1)} N$, and by the prime number
>   theorem one has about a $1/ \log N$ chance of success with each attempt, so the algorithm
>   will succeed with (say) 99% certainty after at most $\log^{O(1)} N$ units of time

**Note:** The notation $\log^c N$ is used for $(\log N)^c$ here. AKS (Agarwal-Kayal-Saxena) algorithm which is used in the paper is a deterministic primality test with original complexity $O(\log^6 N)$ for a number of bitsize $N$, and it's since been improved to $O(\log^3 N)$ later. If this algorithm states that a number is prime, the number is indeed a prime, not subject to errors.